# how do i take data from one sheet (if a cell is filled) to a separate sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula

Here is what I am using

```
=IF('Active Submittals'!G2<>"",('Active Submittals'!A2),"")
```

Where I am struggling is I want the Active Submittals sheet if G2 is filled/not blank to populate the data from ActiveSubmittals A2 to newsheet cell A3, then fill the next cell (A4) and so on, but only if Activesubmittals G is filled

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF('Active Submittals'!G2:G<>"", 'Active Submittals'!A2:A, ))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(IF(G2:G<>"", 'Active Submittals'!A2:A, ))
```

---

### update:

```
=FILTER('Active Submittals'!A2:A, 'Active Submittals'!G2:G<>"")
```

Comment: @RobSands fixed, try now

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RZ7dX3oIWkFRB0tAR_bxnnCJTZFYX79-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It still doesnt work - here is a link to the sheet

Comment: @RobSands you just shared some pdf file

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F7yKDhy1PnKN54YNvTuS0b1lPAOVXh8aQw3LWPQ28Uw/edit

Comment: @RobSands not sure what is your desired result but the formula should be used only in top row - do not drag it downwards - no need, it will autofill. looking on your data my guess would be that you actually don't need IF formula but FILTER. see your shared sheet

Comment: It is a tracking sheet for when people work. When G2 is filled it means they have 'started' so I want to list their name the hourly rate and how many weeks they are working for - but only when they start on the sheet FILTER. Could I just have the line fill out from the ACTIVE SUBMITTALS sheet when the start date is entered then filter FILTER sheet by start date?